# Nginx Port 443 already in use by it self?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am totally new to Nginx and just playing around with my domain, that I had laying around and not used. Thought I might aswell put it to good use and host API on it. But wanted to learn some Nginx first.

When I check the error log I get the following error:

```
2020/09/07 10:49:54 [emerg] 32432#32432: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

When I check "sudo netstat -tulpn":

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32455/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      32455/nginx: master
```

It is nginx it self that is using the port 443?

My config is just overwriting the default nginx conf named "default" in sites-availble and looks like this:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/dotnetdeploy/www_topswagcode_dev.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/dotnetdeploy/www_topswagcode_dev.key;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Aws Lightsail has only port 80 and 22 open per default. I want to kick my nuts so hard....